# Eloquent whereIn error:1390 Prepared statement contains too many placeholders laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple query like this:

```
$arp_terhadap_st_reg = Sfs::select('msisdn')->wherebetween('created', [$datefrom, $dateto])->where('cluster',$cluster)->pluck('msisdn');

$arp_outlet_reg = Arps::whereIn('msisdn',$arp_terhadap_st_reg)->count();
```

Here, $idList is an array, which contains user id, and I have more than 60000 ids.

Everytime, code tells me:

```
"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1390 Prepared statement contains too many placeholders
```

SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `arps` where  `msisdn` in (?, ?, ?, ?,...................

A lot of ? ...

So, how can I fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: exact copy of the question : https://laravel.io/forum/03-28-2014-wherein-error-prepared-statement-contains-too-many-placeholders ???  How??

Comment: not working for me

Comment: This is your real code? or else post the real code

Comment: seems like you stuck in MySQL/MariaDB placeholders limit. it's about 65k. try to separate your query by splitting $idsList

Comment: @YandraAdie see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_chunk` like below

```
$arp_terhadap_st_reg = Sfs::select('msisdn')->wherebetween('created', [$datefrom, $dateto])->where('cluster',$cluster)->get()->toArray();

$arp_outlet_count = 0;

foreach (array_chunk($arp_terhadap_st_reg, 1000) as $arp_terhadap_st) {
    $arp_outlet_reg = Arps::whereIn('msisdn',$arp_terhadap_st)->count();
    $arp_outlet_count = $arp_outlet_count + $arp_outlet_reg;
}
```

You will get your total count in `$arp_outlet_count`

Comment: what about whereNotIn?